# Solr Too many clauses in boolean query. But update to solr.max.booleanClauses not working

Tags: php, solr

I get an ok (400) error from solr when attempting a query that has 2000 clauses.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Solarium\Exception\HttpException: Solr HTTP error: OK (400)
{
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"Too many clauses in boolean query: encountered=2000 configured in solrconfig.xml via maxBooleanClauses=1024",
    "code":400}}
 in
```

To try and fix this I updated the solr.xml (server/solr) file with the following:

```
<int name="maxBooleanClauses">${solr.max.booleanClauses:5000}</int>
```

And restarted the server. But I still get the same error. I am using solr 8.1.

Is there any way I can check which file needs to be updated if it's not this one.

Many thanks

Comment: Are you running in cloud mode or in standalone mode?

Comment: MatsLindh - It's cloud mode. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use the ´downconfig` and `upconfig` commands for `zkcli.sh` to download and upload your configuration - it's stored in Zookeeper and not read from disk directly. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/command-line-utilities.html#zookeeper-cli-examples